# tabulator filter - How to add specific css elements

Tags: css, tabulator

do you know how I can add specific css elements to filters used in tabulator.js:
1) Apply a different background color to different text filter
2) Add a down arrow on the right of each drop down filter box

I have attached a picture of the design and marked the two design elements in red color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32hlu.png)

Looking forward to your response.

Best regards,
G

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7630248), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour).

Answer (score 0):

you can override the css rule, just look wich class name is used and make a css select based on that... you can too put a ID in this input or use a style inline rule

Comment: Thank you very much guys for the quick input. This worked out

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator has a full set of CSS applied to all its elements, you can use these to tweak the styling in any way you like.

A full list of the classes can be found in the [CSS Styling documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/style#css)

And the [Theming Examples Section](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.2#theming) includes a worked example of a manually adjusted theme at the bottom of the section